# Como transformar várias variaveis em uma só PHP

Tags: php, html5

Eu tenho um formulário com 8 campos de input que pegam o valor digitado, eu pego eles pelo POST porém somente 1 dos 8 campos é preenchido pelo usuário, e no POST eu to passando os 8 valores mesmo tendo somente 1 preenchido, tem como eu transformar as 8 variaveis do post em uma só?

No caso estou fazendo isso

```
$nbuffet1 = $_POST['qtdbuffet1'];
$nbuffet2 = $_POST['qtdbuffet2'];
$nbuffet3 = $_POST['qtdbuffet3'];
$nbuffet4 = $_POST['qtdbuffet4'];
$nbuffet5 = $_POST['qtdbuffet5'];
$nbuffet6 = $_POST['qtdbuffet6'];
$nbuffet7 = $_POST['qtdbuffet7'];
$nbuffet8 = $_POST['qtdbuffet8'];

$corpoMSG = " 

<strong>Quantidade Buffet:</strong> $nbuffet1 $nbuffet2 $nbuffet3 $nbuffet4 $nbuffet5 $nbuffet6 $nbuffet7 $nbuffet8<br>

 ";
```

Comment: Experimenta nomear (atributo `name`) todos os campos com o mesmo valor, porém, adicione um par de colchetes no final (ex: `qtdbuffet[]`). Após processado, `$_POST['qtdbuffet']` vai ser um array com tantos valores quantos `input` forem preenchidos.

Comment: beleza, vou testar!

Comment: acho que o ideal seria voce explicar melhor o que seria o campo `qtdbuffetX` talvez o problema seja o tipo de input que voce esta utilizando, postar o trecho do form tambem ajuda.

Comment: Por que você possui 8 campos se somente um será preenchido?

Comment: @BrunoAugusto eu fiz o que você disse, porém ele me trás como resultado "Array" ao invés do número digitado no input

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss eu tenho umas condições que dependendo de um option selecionado ele mostra um tipo de input, por isso tenho 8 campos

Comment: E não pode ser o mesmo? Não consigo ver lógica em existir 8 diferentes.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss eu tenho 8 lojas, cada loja tem uma capacidade máxima, quando seleciono a loja 1, ele abre o input com um número máximo de convidados, o input está configurado para o usuário digitar o limite máximo daquela unidade que foi selecionada, caso ele mude a unidade novamente um outro tipo de input com capacidade máxima é visualizado

Comment: Isso não te impede de ter apenas um campo, basta fazer as devidas configurações com JavaScript. Se você quer mandar apenas um valor, não faz sentido ter 8 campos. Minha opinião.

Comment: @JvsCorrêa Muito provavelmente você está tentando usar diretamente `$_POST['qtdbuffet']` da mesma forma como estava antes (ex: com `echo`/`print`). Com essa mudança no HTML a variável passa a ser um array (doh) e, portanto, precisa ser manipulada como um array, seja iterando ou acessando seus índices. Um array, quando manipulado como string, vai resultar na palavra `Array` mesmo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode concatenar com o operador `.` .

```
    $resultado = $nbuffet1 . ' ' . $nbuffet2 . ' ' . $nbuffet3 . ' ' . $nbuffet4 . ' ' . $nbuffet5 . ' ' . $nbuffet6 . ' ' . $nbuffet7 . ' ' . $nbuffet8;
$corpoMSG = " 

<strong>Quantidade Buffet:</strong> $resultado <br>

 ";
```

ou usar [Heredocs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc):

```
$corpoMSG = <<<EOD
<strong>Quantidade Buffet:</strong>$nbuffet1 $nbuffet2 $nbuffet3 $nbuffet4 $nbuffet5 $nbuffet6 $nbuffet7 $nbuffet8<br>
EOD;
```

Comment: OBS: Se as variáveis forem numéricas use [strval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strval.php) para converte-las em string.

Comment: Isso não gerará múltiplos espaços em branco no valor? E qual a diferença destas soluções para a que foi apresentada na própria pergunta?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss. É exatamente isso que ele quer os espaços em branco entre os valores.

Comment: "porém somente 1 dos 8 campos é preenchido pelo usuário", vide pergunta. Apenas um dos valores é preenchido. E se fosse isso, já havia a solução na própria pergunta.

Comment: E daí qual o problema? Vai aparecer o valor para buffet de jeito que cara quer.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss e se não quiser os espaços basta ser inteligente e retirá-los.

Answer (score 3):

Com PHP você pode verificar qual é o valor preenchido e utilizá-lo. Como os outros valores serão *strings* vazias, basta fazer uma operação lógica entre eles:

```
$quantidade = $_POST['qtdbuffet1'] 
            || $_POST['qtdbuffet2'] 
            || ... 
            || $_POST['qtdbuffet8'];
```

Assim, independente que qual foi preenchido o valor será atribuído à `$quantidade`. Podendo fazer:

```
$corpoMSG = "<strong>Quantidade Buffet:</strong> {$quantidade}<br>";
```

Mas não ha sentido em possuir 8 campos para enviar apenas 1 valor. Veja abaixo como você pode contornar isso utilizando JavaScript.

---

Isso é o que chamamos de problema XY. Você tem um problema na interface, em HTML, mas quer resolvê-lo no PHP. Até consegue, mas vai ser gambiarra.

Como você colocou, você possui 8 opções de escolha na tela para o usuário e conforme a escolha será limitado os valores da quantidade. Você definiu 8 campos diferentes, configurando conforme a necessidade e parece que você apenas exibe um conforme a seleção do usuário. Como consequência você terá 8 valores no PHP sendo que só um foi preenchido. Pela mensagem HTTP você só quer enviar um valor: quantidade. Não importa de onde ela veio. Ter 8 campos para mandar 1 valor não faz sentido algum.

Se precisa de regras de validação diferentes conforme a opção selecionada, use JavaScript:

```js
const loja = document.querySelector('#lojaInput');
const quantidade = document.querySelector('#quantidadeInput');

loja.addEventListener('change', function () {
  quantidade.max = loja.options[loja.selectedIndex].dataset.max;
});
```

```css
input:invalid {
  background-color: pink;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select name="loja" id="lojaInput">
    <option value="1" data-max="10">Loja 1</option>
    <option value="2" data-max="20">Loja 2</option>
    <option value="3" data-max="30">Loja 3</option>
  </select>

  <label>
    Quantidade:
    <input id="quantidadeInput" type="number" name="quantidade" max="10" value="0">
  </label>

  <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Perceba que o valor de `max` do campo `quantidade` é definido pela propriedade `data-max` do `select`. Se selecionada a loja 1 o máximo será 10; loja 2 será 20 e loja 3 será 30.

No PHP, basta pegar o valor `$_POST['quantidade']`. Para validar o valor também no *backend*, utilize o valor de `$_POST['loja']` como referência.

Comment: Agora ficou claro, eu estava seguindo um caminho complicado, não tinha pensado desse jeito, obrigado por me orientar!

Comment: [pt.so] é para isso xD